# Bug in my react Stopwatch code. Issue with clearInterval()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to build a simple stopwatch application in React. The app is rendering okay but the stop and clear buttons are not working. Once started the timer will just keep on running.

Been banging my head on the keyboard for awhile now with this. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

```
class Stopwatch extends Component {
    state = {
      status: false,
      runningTime: 0
    };

    handleClick = () => {
      this.setState(state => {
        if (state.status) {
          clearInterval(this.timer);
        } else {
          const startTime = Date.now() - this.state.runningTime;
          this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ runningTime: Date.now() - startTime });
          });
        }
        return { status: !state.status };
      });
    };
    handleReset = () => {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.setState({ runningTime: 0, status: false });
      };

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      }

    render() {
      const { status, runningTime } = this.state;
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{runningTime}ms</p>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{status ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}</button>
          <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your code works fine see this https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-shape-h7x7o?file=/src/App.js

i just pasted your code here .. everything works.. what's the problem ?

Comment: One weird thing I noticed is in the index.js, if you use React.StrictMode, this code stop working else works fine. @Phil
```
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
```

Comment: Thanks! I have my App.js and index.js files configured wrongly - it's working now. Edit: Yes seems to be linked to the <React.StrictMode>